# Reducing slug size on the Heroku Bamboo stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler

I have seen a number of questions and answers on how to reduce your Heroku slug size but I can't get it to budge. In [How to reduce heroku slug size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256069/how-to-reduce-heroku-slug-size) it is mentioned that there is a bug in Bundler that means that unused gems are not cleaned out.

One of the comments on that question says:

> Note that this issue has now been fixed with Bundler. Opening a support ticket is no longer necessary

I have a few questions:

1. Does this mean that an updated version of Bundler is now used on the
   Heroku Bamboo stack with this fix in it?
2. Do I have any control over which version of Bundler is being used by Heroku?
3. Is Heroku running on a newer version of Bundler then the "release" version?

Comment: So this does not seem to be a problem that effects Bamboo so I think the question might be irrelevant. I think I just got a bit confused...  According to support: "In order to cause your gems to be re-installed on Bamboo, you need to have something in your Gemfile which causes `bundle check` to fail - basically a new dependency, changed version, etc. If you only remove gems, `bundle check` will continue to pass and so bundler's gem cache will not be affected. Once `bundle check` fails, the entire bundler gem cache is wiped away and your gems are re-installed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this mean that an updated version of Bundler is now used on the Heroku Bamboo stack with this fix in it?

> No, as far as I am aware the Bundler has not changed on Bamboo

Do I have any control over which version of Bundler is being used by Heroku?

> No

Is Heroku running on a newer version of Bundler then the "release" version?

> Sometimes, for instance, at the moment they are running a Bundler rc on Cedar.

For reducing slug size, check the Dev Center article:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size

Comment: Thank you very much.  Would I be correct in assuming that the cleaning up of unused gems problem with bundler may still be a problem on Bamboo then? Is this only fixed in the rc versions of Bundler - http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/11/5/besides-being-faster-what-else-is-new-in-bundler-1-1

Answer (score 0):

You may be experiencing the same problem reported in this blog post from a few months ago - http://dazedthots.blogspot.com/2011/07/reducing-slug-size-heroku.html

Comment: Yep, had seen that.  I'm trying to understand whether it is fixed on Bamboo.  I'm guessing it may only be fixed on Cedar based on Bundler versions.